# webdav on iis7.5 - simply cannot make it work

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, webdav, windows

I won't bore with the details, but I've tried every possible combination of settings to get webdav to work on win 2008 r2 and iis 7.5. I'd just like to find out if anyone else has faced challenges making this work and found some magical combination of settings to make it so?

I am running multiple (many) websites on the server, in case this complicates things.

Comment: Unfortunately, detail will be needed. For example: Situation/objective, client being used, problem experienced. It's more complicated than "just does/doesn't work" - it's the settings and the client that determine what's going to work.

Comment: trying to connect from Windows 7, either through shared drive or directly path to end services. The best I've ever had it do is act like it connected but didnt list any files nor allow me to add any.. .as if it weren't really connected at all. I've tried direct IP addresses and domain names, and share names, and any possible combination to make it connect. On the server I've tried it on the default site, on several child sites, using admin privs to even full public permissions. I'm on a dedicated server with full control of all settings, and no firewall blocking issues.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/386/using-the-webdav-redirector/) should still work with WebDAV 7.5, AFAIK.

If it doesn't, the [most](http://www.iwillcrazy.com/2010/05/drive-mapping-to-sharepoint-library-fails/) [common](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2009/12/02/SharePoint-WebDAV-IIS-75-and-Windows-Server-2008-R2.aspx) [reason](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jpradeep/archive/2009/12/01/after-installing-webdav-7-5-explorer-view-does-not-work.aspx) is that Sharepoint/WSS is installed, and gets needy. (the two sets of DAV-related modules both register for the same stuff, apparently).